# Adobe Acrobat Pro 11: I have some sort of grid design I cannot alter

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I used a PDF export feature in LogiReports to create a PDF. This shouldn't much matter, because I have Adobe Acrobat Pro and should be able to edit what it exported. It's created a report with a gridlike design of boxes (it's not perfect grid; see  picture). The thing is, I cannot figure out how to alter or get rid of this grid in Adobe Acrobat Pro.  When I use any PDF-to-HTML converter, this grid gets turned into a full-page PNG.

> How can I find this image in Acrobat and remove it?

[image: Valid XHTML].

Comment: welcome to GDSE! can you share the PDF?  It's really difficult to guess on how the PDF is arranged without being able to see it.  But right off the bat, with the selection tool, if you try to click on the grid, does it highlight the whole thing in a light blue?

Comment: no it doesn't highlight the grid at all when i click on it.  here's a link to the pdf itself: http://asecular.com/ran/2009/z.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded, opened in Acrobat Pro DC (2020), and exported, and while it made a mess of table code, it did export everything just fine.

I would guess that it is a problem with Acrobat 11.

For a short-term fix, you can download a full working 30 day trial of the current version of Acrobat.

I would post the code, it exported but it is too long.  It crammed 106,000 characters onto 17 lines of code.

Comment: It clearly hasn’t heard that the optimal line length is around 50–80 characters.

Comment: well, auto-generated code, in my experience, is ALWAYS messy and ugly.  but sometimes it's what you've got to work with.